# Need guidance in calling WCF service from Silverlight 4

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, wcf

Okay guys, I call upon your combined intellects. I have a web application with a silverlight app that calls a ria service. The ria service is defined inside the web application and everything else is just dandy.

The issue is this.

It is my understanding that in order for the silverlight application to talk and know what the ria service is, you need to add a service reference for that service. The service reference defines the ria service and sets up the connection binding. One of the files it adds is the `ServiceReference.ClientConfig` which has the connection binding in it. During the course of this application's development, this is the way it was set up. And it worked perfectly fine locally and on the dev server.

Unfortunately there were issues when deploying to the clients  in-house server. At this point I was onto other projects while my co-worker continued with the deployment. He soon became frustrated with the goofy errors that were occurring and recruited some help. This dev came in and, albeit got it working, but in order to do so he removed the service reference from the silverlight project but left the `ServiceReference.ClientConfig` which pointed to the location of the service in the web application(but that's it, no definition or explanation as to what the service does and I'm not sure how the silverlight app is supposed to know how to work with it..). This works perfect on my co-workers workstation and he has deployed this version to the clients server fine.

When I open the project it doesn't run at all. And the reason why is that it doesn't know what the service is that i'm using in code. Specifically, it doesn't know where this is (names changed for clarification):

`Imports SilverlightApp.ServiceReference.WebApp.Service`

I have cleaned the solution, completely deleted and got the latest from source control, built the web app first and made sure the asp.net dev server was running so that the address in the `ServiceReference.ClientConfig` resolved correctly. But, alas, it still doesn't know what `Imports SilverlightApp.ServiceReference.WebApp.Service` is.

So, to get it working on my workstation, I added the ServiceReference back but kept the current connection bindings so that it matched the endpoint in the web app web config. and changed the import statement to `Imports SilverlightApp.ServiceReference` and everything works fine.

What is the reason for this insanity?!?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the things you are talking about relate to a WCF service NOT a WCF RIA Service.  They work in quite different ways when consuming them in your client app.

A WCF service will require a service reference and the ServiceReference.ClientConfig.

A WCF RIA Service does not.  The link to the WCF RIA service is set in the silverlight project properties in the Silverlight tab at the bottom. When you build it will generate client side context code in the Generated_Code folder.  Show all files and you will see it.

Hope that helps?

Kevin

Comment: Aha. That would make a lot of sense. My coworker does have the Generated_WCF_Code folder, whereas I do not. However, I've set the link in the project properties and it still won't let me build

Comment: What are the build errors? Do you have all WCF RIA Service tools installed?  Also, look in your website project settings and check your silverlight app is listed in the Silverlight applications tab.

Comment: The build errors occur when I try to instantiate a service client and make calls to it. The import reference doesn't resolve when I open the project on my workstation. And yes, the web project settings are correct and I do have ria services toolkit. And thank you for your help :)